# Unable to validate EditText under setPositiveButton of an AlertDialog

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

I have an `AlertDialog` which requires a password for the user to perform a certain action. But when I try to compare the password to a string to validate if the password is correct, the code doesn't do anything and no errors are shown. When I try to compare the length of the string, the code works flawlessly and executes the code in that condition, it also prompts the user if the `EditText` is empty.

What I would want the code to do is: `if (password == "password" || "otherpassword"){ execute code }`

Here is my method which works by measuring the length of the password:

```
public void redeem(View view) {

        final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);
        AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setTitle("Password")
                .setView(taskEditText)
                .setPositiveButton("Redeem", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                        String password = taskEditText.getText().toString();

                        if (password.length() == 4) {

                            // Execute piece of code

                        } else if (password.isEmpty() == true) {
                            Toast.makeText(PostDetailActivity.this, "The password cannot be empty", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create();
        dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: what is this >>> `final EditText taskEditText = new EditText(this);` ?

Comment: Is this Edittext from Dialog ?

Comment: where are you adding ?

Comment: The code is to add the `EditText` programmatically.

Comment: Whats the problem you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `password.equals("password")`.

In your case it would be:

`if(password.equals("password") || password.equals("someOtherPassword")){
}`

Additionally, to avoid/assure case sensitive result, you can pass `boolean` argument to the `equals()` function. Like `"password".equals("PASSWORD",true)` then it will return false as `password!=PASSWORD`. Similarly, you can use `"password".equals("PASSWORD",false)`, in this case `password==PASSWORD`[**ignoring capital or small characters.**]

Also, in `else if` branch, there is no need to do `else if(password.isEmpty() == true)`. `else if(password.isEmpty())` alone will do the task.